# Group by Vendor Name and Year and Sum Invoice Totals

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes below. I would like to merge both dataframes and calculate the sum of InvoiceAmount per Vendor, per year as the first output. I attempted df1 and df2 merge but merging gets rid of the ones that are not on both dataframes. I attempted groupby then summing invoice total and the columns are all off.

I would also like a second output where the sum of 2017-2018 and 2019-2020 invoices per vendor are calculated to show the difference between the 12 month phases.

DATAFRAME 1:

| Company Code | VendorName | InvoiceDate | InvoiceAmount | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Macys | 1/1/2017 | 100 | 1 |
| 99 | Macys | 1/5/2017 | 5000 | 2 |
| 99 | Macys | 1/1/2018 | 600 | 3 |
| 99 | Macys | 1/5/2018 | 7000 | 4 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/5/2019 | 2000 | 5 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/10/2019 | 4000 | 6 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/5/2020 | 900 | 7 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/10/2020 | 450 | 8 |
| 14 | HM | 5/4/2019 | 360 | 9 |

DATAFRAME 2:

| Company Code | VendorName | InvoiceDate | InvoiceAmount | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Macys | 2/1/2017 | 6000 | 10 |
| 99 | Macys | 9/1/2017 | 400 | 11 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/1/2018 | 620 | 12 |
| 99 | Macys | 9/1/2018 | 7500 | 13 |
| 99 | Macys | 11/1/2019 | 5 | 14 |
| 99 | Macys | 10/10/2019 | 100 | 15 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/5/2020 | 800 | 16 |
| 99 | Macys | 2/10/2020 | 950 | 17 |
| 255 | Hollister | 2/5/2020 | 450 | 18 |

Expected Output1:

| Company Code | VendorName | InvoiceYear | Invoice Total For Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Macys | 2017 | 11,500 |
| 99 | Macys | 2018 | 15,720 |
| 99 | Macys | 2019 | 6,105 |
| 99 | Macys | 2020 | 3,100 |
| 14 | HM | 2019 | 360 |
| 255 | Hollister | 2020 | 450 |

Expected Output2:

| Company Code | VendorName | InvoiceTotal2017-2018 | InvoiceTotal2019-2020 | % Increase/Decrease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Macys | 27,220 | 9,205 | -66% |
| 14 | HM | 0 | 360 | +100% |
| 255 | Hollister | 0 | 450 | +100% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `append` the DataFrames before the `groupby`:

```
df3 = df1.append(df2)
output1 = df3.groupby(["Company Code", "VendorName", df3["InvoiceDate"].dt.year])["InvoiceAmount"].sum().reset_index()

>>> output1
   Company Code VendorName  InvoiceDate  InvoiceAmount
0            14         HM         2019            360
1            99      Macys         2017          11500
2            99      Macys         2018          15720
3            99      Macys         2019           6105
4            99      Macys         2020           3100
5           255  Hollister         2020            450
```

You can then create a `pivot_table`:

```
output2 = pd.pivot_table(output1, 
                         "InvoiceAmount", 
                         ["Company Code", "VendorName"], 
                         output1["InvoiceDate"]<2019, 
                         "sum").rename(columns={True: "2017-2018", False: "2019-2020"})
output2["%Increase/Decrease"] = (output2["2019-2020"].div(output2["2017-2018"])-1).fillna(1)
output2 = output2.fillna(0).reset_index()

>>> output2 
InvoiceDate  Company Code VendorName  2019-2020  2017-2018  %Increase/Decrease
0                      14         HM      360.0        0.0             1.00000
1                      99      Macys     9205.0    27220.0            -0.66183
2                     255  Hollister      450.0        0.0             1.00000
```

Comment: @Meowzz - Edited to solve the second part :)

Comment: @Meowzz - Sorry I've been editing to "beautify" too. So you may have been right

Comment: That wouldn't make sense because for one vendor and 2 years, you will have a list of Invoice Numbers.